# Safe some memory when passing and assigning

Tags: c++, memory, pass-by-value, copy-assignment

I am new to C++ (coming from C#) and I want to get that memory stuff right from the beginning. 
In the following snipped a variable of type `WorldChunkCoordinates` is passed by value to the inline constructor of `WorldChunk` and then the passed Coordinates are assigned to `WorldChunk::Coordinates`, which I believe is a copy operation as well. 
*(copy-assignment operation?)*

If my assumptions are correct then this would be kinda stupid, because I copy the instance twice. I think it would be much more performant if I would pass by value and assign by <s>reference</s> pointer. But `WorldChunk::Coordinates` is not a pointer neither a reference.

```
WorldChunk(WorldChunkCoordinates Coordinates) {
   WorldChunk::Coordinates = Coordinates;
}
```

Is there a way to safe my programm from copying  the instance twice?
**If so, how?**

Also: **Is assigning by = always a copy operation by default?**
And: **How should I know that a specific class may have another copy assignment operation that copies by reference?**

Comment: You usually do `WorldChunk(const WorldChunkCoordinates &Coordinates)` which reduces the amount of copies to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a known and solved problem, called [initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851348/c-constructor-initializer-list-with-complex-assignments) (not to be confused with the container). Looks like

```
 WorldChunk(WorldChunkCoordinates Coordinates) : Coordinates(Coordinates){}
```

Consider using lower case letters for variable names.

You could also use

```
 WorldChunk(const WorldChunkCoordinates &Coordinates) : Coordinates(Coordinates){}
```

but it is not obvious that dereferencing is faster than copying, especially when taking compiler optimizations into account.

Comment: I think this answer and the other two answers could be combined into one answer for "the best answer"

Comment: @KABoissonneault Edited accordingly.

Comment: Do you know what happens behind the scenes of the init list? Because as far as I am concerned the parameter is now passed by value, stored on the stack and cannot/should not leave the method by takinga reference out of the scope. (Wouldn't it make more sense o pass by const ref as in the other examples? and then use the init list?)

Comment: @NoelWidmer Maybe. Rule of thumb is to pass stuff bigger than 8 bytes as a reference, rest by value. Compiler optimization probably takes care of it.

Comment: I would use references for >= 64bit. Sounds good yes. Are you saying the compiler may modify that as well? I wasn't aware that compiler optimization takes it that far. And in C# we usually use Capitals. But I figured I should switch because everything is in lower-case. Not sure whyy though.

Comment: @nwp No it is not a ref. As said in my question. it is not a pointer nor a ref.

Comment: @NoelWidmer He's talking about actual C++ references, not C#'s auto-deferencing handles.

Passing through reference in C++ can be applied to any type, it's not bound to whether your object is a class or not.

Comment: @KABoissonneault I know what he means and I am aware of that. There are no value or reference types in C++. everything can be everything. The definition looks like that: WorldChunkCoordinates Coordinates;

Answer (score 1):

first of all a simple solutuion:

change your method to:

```
WorldChunk(const WorldChunkCoordinates& Coordinates) {  WorldChunk::Coordinates = Coordinates;}
```

This will lead to a single assignment instruction because coordinates is a reference.

The default constructed assignment operator assigns memberwise.
The parameter of the assignment operator is (usually) a const reference to the object so that you don't copy the parameter.

By the way a little tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ which is very good in my point of view.

Comment: I am aware of that tutorial (Actually have a printed version right next to me) Thanks for the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The convention in C++ for user type function arguments is to pass by const reference (const MyType&) for input arguments, and by reference for in-out arguments (MyType&).